# Identify if a file is List of JSON Record or a Single JSON record

Tags: json, file

I have Json input that can be in two forms

1. List of JSON Records: Sample Record `{"l7ProtocolID":"dhcp","packets_out":1,"bytes_out":400,"start_time":1454281199898,"flow_sample":0,"duration":102,"path":["base","ip","udp","dhcp"],"bytes_in":1200,"l4":[{"client":"68","server":"67","level":0}],"l2":[{"client":"52:54:00:50:04:B2","server":"FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF","level":0}],"l3":[{"client":"::ffff:0.0.0.0","server":"::ffff:255.255.255.255","level":0}],"flow_id":"81454281200000731489","applicationID":"dhcp","packets_in":1}`

there might be n number of such records in a file seperated by new line character.

2. The file itself is one record:  Sample Record: `{
   "status": "ok",
   "response": {
       "submissions": [
           {
               "id": "59434767",
               "timestamp": "2011-11-21 09:21:53",
               "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0",
               "remote_addr": "192.168.1.1",
               "payment_status": "",
               "data": [
                   {
                       "field": "13776121",
                       "value": "Baylor Dallas"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13776401",
                       "value": "CHF"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13777966",
                       "value": "John Doe"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13780027",
                       "value": "9999"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13778165",
                       "value": "None of the above"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13778985",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13778280",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13778424",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13778290",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13778324",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13778864",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   }
               ]
           },
           {
               "id": "59474875",
               "timestamp": "2011-11-21 17:01:22",
               "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0",
               "remote_addr": "192.168.1.1",
               "payment_status": "",
               "data": [
                   {
                       "field": "13776121",
                       "value": "Healthsouth,"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13776401",
                       "value": "Pneumonia"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13777966",
                       "value": "Jane Doe"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13780027",
                       "value": "390"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13778165",
                       "value": "Experienced a fall?"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13861153",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13780018",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13780006",
                       "value": "No"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13780023",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   },
                   {
                       "field": "13780024",
                       "value": "Yes"
                   }
               ]
           }
       ],
       "total": 2,
       "pages": 1
   }
   }`

Is there any possible way to Identify between them.

Answer (score 0):

you can't determine what is written in the file unless you will read it.

i think you really need to read all files.. parse its data to determine if its a list or not. ^_^

Comment: I understand it can not be achieved without reading file. Can you please help with some snippet